# error could not find or load main class when using ant to execute java/junit tests

Tags: java, class, ant, load, program-entry-point

I am trying to run tests written in Java using ant. The java files compiles fine but when run, gives an error saying: `Could not find or load main class.`

I was able to build projects with no problems up until yesterday but all of a sudden it stopped working.

My Java installation and classpaths do not seem to have a problem because I could run Java files without requiring `Ant`. The problem occurs when I use `Ant` to execute the java code.

Comment: Without specific code examples impossible to help you. This is **always** a classpath issue.